# How to merge nested dictionaries at different nested level?

Tags: python

I would like to merge these two nested dictionaries :

```
dict1 = {'NYSE': {'day': {'USD': {'missing': ['z', 'y', 'x']}}}}
dict2 = {'NYSE': {'hour': {'USD': {'missing': ['z', 'y', 'x']}}}}
```

So the result would be something like this :

```
{
    'NYSE': {
        'day': {
            'USD': {
                'missing': ['z', 'y', 'x']
            }
        },
        'hour': {
            'USD': {
                'missing': ['z', 'y', 'x']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In some situations I need to merge the second level of the dictionaries like this :

```
dict1 = {'NYSE': {'day': {'USD': {'missing': ['z', 'y', 'x']}}}}
dict3 = {'NYSE': {'day': {'EUR': {'missing': ['z', 'y', 'x']}}}}
```

Is there a simple way to do this ?

When I use `dict1.update(dict2)` it doesn't gives the expected result because `dict2` becomes `dict1`.

I could do this but it is not flexible at all.

```
dict1['NYSE']['hour'] = {'USD': {'missing': ['z', 'y', 'x']}}
```

Thank you,

Comment: How about wrapping this data in class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
dict1['NYSE'].update(dict2['NYSE'])
```

Comment: thre is a typo, it should be: dict1['NYSE'].update(dict2['NYSE'])

Comment: It's fixed. Thanks!